# Protractor: how to test load bar

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor, automated-tests

I am testing a login page that has a load bar.
My scenario should test if a load bar displayed when a user clicks on "Login" button.
I created the following function for the test-flow but it fails always with the error of timed out.

```
 isLoadBarDisplayed: function () {
    var thePage = this.page;      
    thePage.userNameField.sendKeys(randVal);
    thePage.passwordField.sendKeys(randVal);

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    thePage.LoginBtn.submit()

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(thePage.loadBar), 5000, false);

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
},
```

The another code yields false always:

```
    .......
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    return thePage.LoginBtn.click().then(function(){
       return thePage.loadBar.isDisplayed()
    })

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
}
```

Any ideas are very welcome!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your `loadBar` locator is correct?

Comment: I did a short investigation with "elementor":
This is a full tag of my load bar: 
<img src="Images/login-waiting.gif" height="40" width="200" ng-show="loading" class="ng-hide">.

I use the following locator for loadBar variable:
element(by.css('[ng-show="loading"]'))
    
When credentials are loading and the load bar appears on the screen , the "class" attribute is disappearing but isDisplayed() command still returns false value

What is wrong here?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you definitely need to turn the sync off, but, could you move `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` to `afterEach()` to avoid the sync being turned off prematurely?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have to keep the steps order in order to reach the correct answer (my mistake and so stupid).
In my case, the test steps are outside of Jasmine framework therefore I used a thread of then() functions. The answer is posted  below. Thank you so much, @alecxe

Answer (score 0):

In order to know another way to solve the issue, see the comments above. In my case the following part of code works correct:

```
    var result

    thePage.userNameField.sendKeys(randVal);

    return thePage.passwordField.sendKeys(randVal).then(function () { 
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    }).then(function () { 
        thePage.LoginBtn.submit()
        thePage.loadBar.isDisplayed().then(function (answer) {
            result = answer;
        });

    }).then(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        return result;
    });
```